# Selecting top3 from a table

Tags: sql

How to select top3 values from a table.
Please let me know the query for selecting top 3 values of the table.
Thank you.

Comment: Top 3 what from what table? We need to know the schema. Knowing what DBMS you are talking about would be helpful as well.

Comment: Just I need to select top 3 values from table that's it

Comment: Dude, what RDBMS (database) are you using? That will impact the answer...

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Table
```

Do you need the top 3 values based on some criterion?

Comment: Yeah. I have another query too. Where I faced this question."Select top 3 from table and assign them in descending order and ascending order.

Comment: A full description of your problem would help to understand what you're trying to do.  It would also probably get the folks voting to close the question off your back... :)

Comment: No I just need to select top3 from a table for now. My another question is after selecting top3 from the table I need to assign them again in reverse order

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 3 * From table where col = value
```

Comment: While I'm executing this query I'm getting an error

Comment: See, this is why knowing your RDBMS is helpful, because most vendors have slightly different ways of implementing this behaviour.  There isn't really any one 'General' answer that will always work, that I'm aware of.